Satmar Commentary on the Chumash
Is there any particular Sefer/source that is good for learning Satmar outlooks on the Torah? Preferably in English. Or even so, does anyone know of a Satmar interpretation/commentary for Bereshis 19:1-38?

Tried Divrei Yoel?

You should give this site a chance. The Divrei Yoel is translated to English (adaption).
In Hebrew, refer to the sefer "Toros VeSichos MiBeis Raboseinu", a collection of different teachings from Satmar on the weekly parasha

You might want to try the English translation of selected writings of the Satmar Rebbe's Divrei Yoel, compiled by Rabbi Joseph Kolakowski. It has five separate seforim on each of the books of the Torah.
If you're specifically after a piece in Bereishis, try the first cheilek here / here (also available for free on the kindle!)
